# Different datasource for adding and changing rendering component content

Tags: sitecore-client

We have multiple sites. And for each site has content folder called `"data"`. Our client wants that if he is going to add a rendering component to the page, the datasource would be coming from the `data` folder of the current editing site. But if he is going to change the content of a particular existing rendering component from the site, the datasource should be coming from the `data` folder of ALL SITES. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

- To return the datasource from "Data" folder of the current editing site, add below query in "Datasource Location" in rendering level:

  query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site Root']/Global/Data
- To return the datasource from the "Data" folder of all sites you use this query:

  query:..//*[@@templatename='Data template name']

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I am already done with this and what I need is the flexibility of the datasource. When adding component, it should show different datasource. When editing that component, it will show different datasource.

Comment: if you have SXA you could do it with $site/Data query